# jQuery doesn't allow dynamic event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

```
 var action = 'click';
 if (action == 'click') {
      $('#element').on(action, function() {
           // do something...
      })
 } else if (action == 'mouseenter') {
      $('#element').on(action, function() {
           // do something completely different...
      })
 }
```

Whenever `action` changes, the event goes off according to the old action; It doesn't change dynamically.  I also tried:

```
 $('#element').on(action, function() {
      if (action == 'click') {
           // do something...
      } else if (action == 'mouseenter') {
           // do something else...
      }
 });
```

For `smart snowflakes`: I need one element to be treated differenly depending on what `action` is, not simultaneous. And the `action` itself is changeable by the client.

Edit #2: I'm not trying to have different results depending on what event was used on the element. If client chooses, say, "play mode", then action is set to mouseenter, in which case the #element should NOT be clickable* and only operate when hovered!

Comment: My answer is to just not it this way... You are actually not dynamically adding event listeners, you are just adding logical operators for absolutely no reason.

Comment: ryan0319, well then what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @PyRoss you need to edit this question to make it more clear what your desired results are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple events this way. Then have if else statements depending on the value of e.type.

```
$('#element').on('click mouseover mouseout',function(e){
    console.log(e.type)
    if(e.type == 'click')
          //handle click
    else if(e.type == 'mouseover')
          //handle mouseover
     ...
})
```

EDIT: jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pe8awhyL/2/

HTML

```
<button id="click">
click
</button>
<button id="mouseover">
mouseover
</button>
<button id="mouseout">
mouseout
</button>
```

JS: The listener logic works as long as 'action' is set to a recognizable event.

```
var action = 'click';

$('div').on('click mouseover mouseout',function(e){
    if(e.type == action)
      //The event is equal to the expected action, handle accordingly
})

$('button').on('click',function(){
    action = $(this).attr('id');
})
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to have different results depending on what event was used on the element. If client chooses, say, "play mode", then `action` is set to `mouseenter`, in which case the `#element` should NOT be clickable* anymore (should not have any effect when clicked) and only operate when hovered, and vice versa.

Comment: Actually i think it is what you're trying to do, you just need to recognize the use case and extend it. When the event occurs and you're checking e.type, simply add an 'AND' condition in the same if statement that checks if 'action' is the same event. Added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `bind()` and `unbind()` as a way to dynamically change your functions. I would definitely look at possibly adding namespaces to them too for better tracking. https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

I have inlined the jquery example below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>unbind demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  button#theone {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Bind Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Unbind Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>
 
<script>
function aClick() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "#theone" )
    .bind( "click", aClick )
    .text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "#theone" )
    .unbind( "click", aClick )
    .text( "Does nothing..." );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need one element to be treated differenly depending on what `action` is, not simultaneous. And the `action` itself is changeable by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like :

```
<div id="element">
    Click
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <button id="click">
    Activate Click Event
    </button>
    <button id="mouseenter">
    Activate mouseEnter Event
    </button>


<script>


  $("button").click(function()
 {
   var action = this.id; // you may use any other criteria to match this up
   $('#element').off();  // removes all delegated events
   if (action == 'click') 
   {
        $('#element').on(action, function() {
           alert('click invoked');
        });
   } else if (action == 'mouseenter') {       
         $('#element').on(action, function() {
         alert('mouseenter invoked');
       });
   }
 });
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/98nnvjqm/2/

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is an expected behavior. Because, you are only registering back to back events on each check. So firstly, it will register `click` event. Once the action changes to `mouseenter`, it will register `mouseenter` event (I assume that you will trigger that code once the action changes)

What you have to do is remove the existing events Off the element before registering the new one. You can read more about [Off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in the docs. You can even find some working examples in the above link

ie,

```
function actionChanged() {
    if(action == "mouseenter") {
        $( "body" ).off( "click", "#element", clickFunction );
        $( "body" ).on( "mouseenter", "#element", mouseEnterFunction );
    } else if (action == 'click') {
        $( "body" ).off( "mouseenter", "#element", mouseEnterFunction );
        $( "body" ).on( "click", "#element", clickFunction );
    }
}
```